# bitwise complement in Delphi. (Translating C# ~ operator)

Tags: c#, delphi, serial-port

I have the C# code for calculating the checksum byte for commands sent to a specific serial device. I need help to translate to this function to Delphi 10.x for Windows and also for Delphi Android (if it's different).

C# code

```
public byte CheckSum(byte[] btAryBuffer, int nStartPos, int nLen)
{
   byte btSum = 0x00;
   for (int nloop = nStartPos; nloop < nStartPos + nLen; nloop++ )
   {
      btSum += btAryBuffer[nloop];
   }
   return Convert.ToByte(((~btSum) + 1) & 0xFF);
}
```

Delphi code

```
function CalcCheckSum(buffer: TArray<byte>; nStartPos: Integer; nLen: Integer): Byte;
var i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  i := nStartPos;
  while i < nStartPos + nLen do
  begin
     Result := Result + buffer[i];
     Inc(i);
  end; 
  Result := ???
end;
```

Comment: You can use a for loop on delphi. Also, Delphi's operators are documented. You could read the documentation.

Comment: No. I just have some suggestions on how you might become a better developer. Take it or leave it. In case you change your mind the documentation is here http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Logical_.28Bitwise.29_Operators

Comment: In case you did not know how a computer handles negative values and 2's-complement: `Result := -Result` is equivalent with `Result := (not Result) + 1`. I'm surprised that the C# code did not use that optimization.

Comment: @LURD Why should the coder write it that way. If it's an optimization then the compiler can do it. Anyway, byte is unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Result := ((not Result) + 1) and $FF;
```

Comment: See if it compiles first (-:  , this was from memory.

Comment: You don't need to test on a device first to know that this is correct. If you want to test it, pass both versions some example data.

Comment: @nolaspeaker - this particualr function can easily be copied to a new empty C# project. You may want to set up unittests for both languages, especially if you have more of these.